# Кастомизация строки ajax-поиска товара

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Магазин на WP+WooCommerce. Есть вариативные товары со статусом "Черновик" и, при этом, "В наличии" (товар "аджика пастеризованная" на фото):
[image: https://ibb.co/MS7GVjp]
При добавлении этих товаров через админку в заказ вариации этого товара доступны к добавлению, что вводит в заблуждение менеджеров, которые работают с заказами:
[image: https://ibb.co/fCYm88M]
Как можно отключить показ черновиков в строке поиска?
Пока нарыл такой код (в разных вариантах, но смысл один, все они используют фильтр `woocommerce_json_search_found_products`):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products', function( $products ) {   
    foreach ($products as $id => $title) :
        if(wc_get_product($id)->get_status() == 'draft')
            unset( $products[$id] );    
    endforeach; 
    return $products;   
}, 10, 1);
```

но он не работает. Черновики товаров всё равно доступны к добавлению в заказ.

Comment: Вставьте картинки в тело вопроса, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился следующим кодом:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products', function( $products ) {   
    foreach ($products as $id => $title) :  
        if(get_post_type($id) == 'product_variation' && wp_get_post_parent_id($id)->get_status() == 'draft')
            unset( $products[$id] );    
    endforeach; 
    return $products;   
}, 10, 1);
```

Т.е. статус "Черновик" должен проверяться не у вариации, а у "родителя".